# What does : newImg(newImg < 1) = 0 , means ?

Tags: matlab

Consider this code :

```
n = 100; 
m = 200;
newImg = zeros(n,m);
% 
% newImg is changed somewhere in the code 
newImg(newImg < 1) = 0
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: Downvoters , I don't see the reason for that , but have it your way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of

```
newImg(newImg < 1) = 0
```

is: take all entries of `newImg` that currently are less than `1`, and set them to `0`.

It uses the concept of [`logical indexing`](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).